# In Python 3.x, how do I replace certain items in a list then print list as a string

Tags: python, string, list

I'm making a small word game that makes gibberish out of a word. User gives a syllable and a word (example: ug and astronaut) and the program replaces all vowels with the syllable, unless it's a double vowel. Astronaut becomes Astugonugaut. If the syllable was ib and the word was demonstrate, the product would be dibemibonstribate.

I know that I need to have some sort of loop that runs through each letter in the word and determines if it's a vowel, double vowel, first letter, yada yada and work with that. I can't seem to figure out how to do that though.

I have something like this

```
def gibberizer(word):
    for char in range(len(word)):
        print(char)
    word.insert(4,gib1)
    print(word)
```

the insert line will insert the syllable where it should be, but I can't figure out how to have it do it automatically.

I also don't know how to get it to print the list as a string. I tried using .join, but I'm a bit of an idiot and probably did it wrong.

Comment: Your examples do not match at all the description of your rules: "the program replaces all vowels with the syllable, unless it's a double vowel".
Astronaut -> Ugstrugnaut; Demonstrate -> Dibmibnstribtib

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` method for strings and `if` conditions may be useful.

For join: `", ".join(aList)` or whatever delimiter you want this will print the items in the list as comma delimited.